# time series data for every 10 seconds

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

I have data collected by sensors in every 10 seconds. This collection started from 2016-04-01T00:00:13 and ends on 2017-04-30T23:56:58. That means nearly one year. The file contains two columns "DateTimeStamp" and "data".
So, I use following frequency in R tool:

```
sc<-read.csv(file="Temper4One.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=F)
sc$V1<-as.POSIXct(sc$V1,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz= "CET") 
sc_xts<-xts(sc$V2,order.by=as.POSIXct(sc$V1,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz= "CET"))
sc.ts=ts(as.numeric(sc_xts), start=c(2016,1), end=c(2017,1), frequency = 24*6*365)
```

I am confused it is correct or not?

I used ACF function with follwoing:

```
acf(sc.ts, lag=40)
```

[image]

I want to understand why the lags (in x axis) are very very small.

UPDATE 1:
the output of dput(sc[1:20, ]) is:

```
> dput(sc[1:20, ])
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1459461613, 1459462217, 1459462821, 
1459463424, 1459464028, 1459464633, 1459465234, 1459465841, 1459466445, 
1459467048, 1459467654, 1459468258, 1459469032, 1459469636, 1459470243, 
1459470844, 1459471447, 1459472052, 1459472657, 1459473260), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "CET"), V2 = c(14.5423058159053, 14.458881293279, 
14.2091612741173, 14.458881293279, 14.375549570652, 14.7931443820062, 
14.7094365363843, 14.8769483232661, 14.7094365363843, 14.5423058159053, 
14.375549570652, 14.375549570652, 14.5423058159053, 14.6258239563275, 
14.458881293279, 14.6258239563275, 14.5423058159053, 14.2923098342188, 
14.2091612741173, 13.8774627350418)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please post a data sample--maybe the first 20 rows of `sc` after running the first line of your code. To post the data, paste into your question to the output of `dput(sc[1:20, ])`.

Comment: @eipi10, i have pasted the output. Please comment on it.